# Windows XP not mapping drives after logging into a windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, windows-7

Bit of background. We map out network drives via GPO. This works fine for both XP and windows 7 clients. The GPO’s are served by a Win2008R2 DC.

I have a user that has to works in 2 departments. The one she has got a Windows XPx32 computer in the other she has a Win7x64 computer. If she logs into the Win7 PC her network drives are mapped fine. But when she logs back into the Win XP PC the drives are no longer mapped, until I re-map these manually (or reboot a few times and they come back). Once the drives have been remapped wheather manual or via a few reboots and the GPO re-applying, this works fine until the next loging to the Win7 client.

Running GPudpate.exe /force dose not work (Even when saying Yes to logoff)

Running  RSOP I can see all the policy’s apart from the mapped drives are applied. I have installed KB943729 to give legacy GPO support for the XP client. 
The user hasn’t got a roaming profile (and I don’t think it will make much difference)

Thoughts?

Comment: If you're not using roaming profiles, I can't fathom how the previous login would have any effect whatsoever. Are you 100% sure that the Win7 thing isn't a red herring?

Comment: It only happens when usess log into Windows 7. I have made them use differnt clients and this still happens.

Comment: You haven't made it clear: Are you using Roaming Profiles?